# Difference between "Riki's Sange and Yasha" and "Sange and Yasha" cosmetics

Tags: dota-2

On the Dota 2 market, I see the cosmetic items ["Sange and Yasha"](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/570/Sange%20and%20Yasha) and ["Riki's Sange and Yasha"](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/570/Riki%27s%20Sange%20and%20Yasha). What is the difference between these two items?

Answer (score 1):

Cosmetically there is no difference. The difference is in the name and when they were available or given out.